# My .settext in one fragment dont save after changing the fragment an then go back

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Im am working with two fragment an replacing them by pressing a button. In one of them i having a edittext which on i change with .settext and make it not editable with . setEnabled(false). Now i the Problem wenn i go the other fragment an then back it dont save.

> team1_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.team1_1);
> comit1 = view.findViewById(R.id.comit1);

> setonclick...
> team1_1.setText(team1_1.getText().toString()); team1_1.setEnabled(false);

Please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save the text in a string which is null by default.  check if the string is not null.  If is isn't null, then set the text to the view in the fragment's onCreateView() method.  This will ensure the data is kept between fragment transactions. Ex:

```
private String text = null;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle sIS) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, sIS);
    team1_1.setText(text);
    /*Other Frag Logic*/
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    //binding = null; Only use if you are using viewbinding
    text = team1_1.getText().toString();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No it dont work

Comment: Firstly i doesnt work, but when i did the String static it works thank you so muchhh. ;-)